# Remove an html button using js

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a bit of code below that creates a button on a html form. When a user has entered some information using the button I want the form to reflect this by removing the button and replacing it with just plain text. I have tried getting the inner html and using divs but nothing is working can anybody help please? I am not looking for anyone to write code for me just a few pointers would be great.

```
  <td class="col1"><h3>Associated with :</h3></td>
  <td class="col3">
  <input type="button" 
  value="Associate this job " 
  onclick="associate()" 
/></td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `span` with an `id`attribute around whatever it is you want to change. When it's time, here's all you need to do:

```
    document.getElementById("spanIDhere").innerHTML = "Your text here";
```

So for instance, you'd have the line:

```
    <span id="associatespan">
        <input type="button" value="Associate this job" onclick="associate()" />
    </span>
```

and your script would say:

```
    document.getElementById("associateSpan").innerHTML = "Look, no more button!";
```

Answer (score 3):

Put it in a DIV and put the text in a DIV that is hidden. When the user starts to type, hide the button DIV and show the text DIV.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look at one of the Javascript toolkits that make it very easy. For example, I have used [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) for this. The specific method is [Element.hide()](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/hide/) and there's example usage on the page.