# How to use Javascript to remove html button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm new at programming, so it would be easier for me if you could explain what the code is doing too. But anyway, at a certain point in my Javascript, I want to make a button disappear and replace it with the words that were on the button before. I've tried looking at a few different other questions about things like this, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504565/how-to-remove-button-from-form-element-javascript) was too confusing, and I didn't understand it, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507093/remove-an-html-button-using-js), didn't work for some reason. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

EDIT

Here is some of my HTML:

```
<div class="inside">
<form name="form" onsubmit="return false">
    <button id="id1" class="buttonthird" name="Button1" onclick="myFunction1()">Button 1</button>
    <button id="id2" class="buttonthird" name="Button2" onclick="myFunction2()">Button 2</button>
    <button id="id3" class="buttonthird" name="Button3" onclick="myFunction3()">Button 3</button><br/>
    <button id="id4" class="buttonthird" name="Button4" onclick="myFunction4()">Button 4</button>
    <button id="id5" class="buttonthird" name="Button5" onclick="myFunction5()">Button 5</button>
    <button id="id6" class="buttonthird" name="Button6" id="p2" onclick="myFunction6()">Button 6</button>
    </form>
    <h1 class="counter"> <span id="number">0</span> guesses</h1>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery, or does this have to be pure js?

Comment: Please show some code so that we know whether it is an input button or a button tag, has an id, has a class, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML:

```
<div>
    <button id="my-btn">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Your JS:

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("my-btn"),
    mySpan = document.createElement("span");
mySpan.innerHTML = myBtn.innerHTML ;
myBtn.parentNode.replaceChild(mySpan, myBtn);
```

Comment: I didn't get what you mean

Comment: to style using css, after myspan is set add this line to add an id:  mySpan.setAttribute('id', 'buttonID'); then style the id accordingly using css

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your button is in a containing element e.g.

```
<div id="button_container"><input type="button" name="x" value="y" /></div>
```

You can simply replace the contents of the inner div, like so:

```
document.getElementById('button_container').innerHTML="y";
```